# PHP - Is there a simple way to set a $_SESSION for multiple variables?

Tags: php, session

I have the following code that I require to define for each `$_SESSION`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['profile_status']) OR isset($_SESSION['building_name']) OR isset($_SESSION['building_street']) OR isset($_SESSION['building_postcode']) OR isset($_SESSION['building_locality']) OR isset($_SESSION['building_country'])){
    $getProfileStatus = $_SESSION['profile_status'];
    $buildingNameSelected = $_SESSION['building_name'];
    $streetAddSelected = $_SESSION['building_street'];
    $postcodeAddSelected = $_SESSION['building_postcode'];
    $localityAddSelected = $_SESSION['building_locality'];
    $countryAddSelected = $_SESSION['building_country'];
    $vatNumber = $_SESSION['vat_number'];
    $businessWebsite = $_SESSION['business_website'];
    $businessEmail = $_SESSION['business_email'];
    $contactPerson = $_SESSION['contact_person'];
    $telephone1 = $_SESSION['telephone_1'];
    $telephone2 = $_SESSION['telephone_2'];
    $telephone3 = $_SESSION['telephone_3'];
    $telephone4 = $_SESSION['telephone_4'];
}
```

Is there a cleaner/better way tan doing `isset($_SESSION` for each variable without getting any errors.

I tried using a foreach loop but I got errors that variables weren't defined.

```
$sessionArrays = array(
    'profile_status' => array(
        'variable' => $getProfileStatus,
        'session' => 'profile_status',
        ),
    'building_name' => array(
        'variable' => $buildingNameSelected,
        'session' => 'building_name',
        ),
    'building_street' => array(
        'variable' => $streetAddSelected,
        'session' => 'building_street',
        ),
    'building_postcode' => array(
        'variable' => $postcodeAddSelected,
        'session' => 'building_postcode',
        ),
    'vat_number' => array(
        'variable' => $vatNumber,
        'session' => 'vat_number',
        ),
    'business_website' => array(
        'variable' => $businessWebsite,
        'session' => 'business_website',
        ),
    'business_email' => array(
        'variable' => $buildingNameSelected,
        'session' => 'business_email',
        ),
    'contact_person' => array(
        'variable' => $contactPerson,
        'session' => 'contact_person',
        ),
    'building_name' => array(
        'variable' => $buildingNameSelected,
        'session' => 'building_name',
        ),
    'telephone_1' => array(
        'variable' => $telephone1,
        'session' => 'telephone_1',
        ),
    'telephone_2' => array(
        'variable' => $telephone2,
        'session' => 'telephone_2',
        ),
    'telephone_3' => array(
        'variable' => $telephone3,
        'session' => 'telephone_3',
        ),
    'telephone_4' => array(
        'variable' => $telephone4,
        'session' => 'telephone_4',
        ),
    );

foreach ($sessionArrays as $sessionArray){
    if(isset($_SESSION[$sessionArray['session']])){
        $sessionArray['variable'] = $_SESSION[$sessionArray['session']];
    }else{
        $sessionArray['variable'] = null;
    }
```

Comment: whats wrong with isset()?

Comment: You'd just have to use the isset() on each single assignment, for example inside a foreach. Or iterate over the keys of `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @syck I think that its getting too long that's why.

Comment: You get errors like `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: getProfileStatus` etc because these variables like $getProfileStatus are not defined anywhere.

Comment: Thansk @TomaszTurkowski

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using `foreach` and using `empty()` instead of `isset()` then you are sure this value is set and not empty.

```
$keys = [
    'profile_status', 
    'building_name', 
    'building_street', 
    'building_postcode', 
    'building_locality', 
    'building_country', 
    'vat_number', 
    'business_website', 
    'business_email', 
    'contact_person', 
    'telephone_1', 
    'telephone_2', 
    'telephone_3', 
    'telephone_4'
    ];

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    if (empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
        echo $key . ' is missing in session!';  
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with the foreach loop but I still got an error.